# Gamma glm log link - what does predicted values mean

Tags: generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution, link-function, logarithm

Does the predict function in R for gamma glm with log link predict the actual values or the mean value?

There is a gamma glm model in R with log link. Using predict(model,data,type = 'response') to get predictedval val in the scale of response variable, If I use use my predicted value inside qgamma function as qgamma(0.9,shape = 1/dispersion, scale = predictedval*dispersion) what will the output of qgamma signify?

Comment: Glm ''like'' regression predicts the mean value given the covariates. Selecting response in predict fuction back transforms the prediction out of the link scale (inverses the link),so the prediction is on same scale as the dependent variable.

Comment: Once the link is inversed will the predicted value still not be the arithmetic mean and not the original y variable?

Comment: If the transformed value is indeed an arithmetic mean then how can I know how close the distribution represents the overall population? Is out of time validation possible with gamma glm? If yes how?

Comment: If you "overfit"  the model you can return back the exact value of y, but when modeling your trying generalize  and approximate. It may not be the same as the arithmatic mean because the mean is estimated using maximum likelihood and is conditional on the included dependent variables. The gamma distribution is very flexible and is in fact a series of distributions that changes shape depending on the response  (variance changes with mean). The gamma distribution requires the data to be positive definite and continuous, if you fit those conditions the gamma distribution will quite often fit .

Comment: The Pearson residuals should be normally distributed and show no signs of heteroscedacity. For more on model evaluation  see: https://www.crcpress.com/Extending-the-Linear-Model-with-R-Generalized-Linear-Mixed-Effects-and/Faraway/p/book/9781498720960

Comment: Thanks for that.. can you help with the other part of the question as well??

Comment: Are you attempting to return the upper bound of the 90 percent confidence interval

Comment: It was done by somebody else my understanding is pretty much the same as yours so wanted to be sure of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was hoping someone else would expand upon my comments in a full answer, but here is mine, incase anyone needs help with a similar question.

**1. Response to what does it predict**

Glm ''like'' regression predicts the mean value given the independent variables. Selecting response in predict function back transforms the prediction out of the link scale (inverses the link), so the prediction is on the same scale as the dependent variable. If you "overfit" the model you can return back the exact value of y, but when modeling you're trying to generalize and approximate. It may not be the same as the arithmetic mean because the mean is estimated using maximum likelihood and is conditional on the included independent variables.

**2. Response to how to "know" if the gamma distribution is right for my data**

The gamma distribution is very flexible and is, in fact, a series of distributions that changes shape depending on the response (variance changes with mean). The gamma distribution requires the data to be positive definite and continuous if you fit those conditions the gamma distribution will quite often fit. Additionally, the Pearson residuals should be normally distributed and show no signs of heteroscedasticity. For more on model evaluation see: https://www.crcpress.com/Extending-the-Linear-Model-with-R-Generalized-Linear-Mixed-Effects-and/Faraway/p/book/9781498720960

**3. Response to what happens when I use the qgamma function?**

I am not 100% sure why the person you borrowed your sample code from is using the qgamma function. However, it looks to me like they are trying to return the 90th percent confidence limit. This is the code I use to return back  95% confidence limits on predictions.

```
 preds_link = predict(model, newdata = test_data,
                     type = "link",
                     se.fit = TRUE)# use the glm to make predictions, also provides  std. error
 critval <- 1.96 # critical value for approx 95% CI
 upper_ci_link <- preds_link$fit + (critval * preds_link$se.fit)# estimate upper CI for prediction on link scale
 lwr_ci_link <- preds_link$fit - (critval * preds_link$se.fit)# estimate lower CI for prediction on link scale
 fit_link <- preds_link$fit# returns fited value
 upper_ci <- model$family$linkinv(upper_ci_link)
 lwr_ci <- model$family$linkinv(lwr_ci_link)
 fit <- model$family$linkinv(fit)
 preds_link = data.frame(fit,lwr_ci,upper_ci,
                    fit_link,lwr_ci_link,
                    upper_ci_link)# puts predictions, CI in a single dataframe
 colnames(preds_link) = c("Prediction","LCL", "UCL",
                     "Link_Prediction","Link_LCL", "Link_UCL")# give variables logical names
```

Prediction, LCL, and UCL: Prediction and Confidence Limits on response scale (i.e., same scale as data)

Link_Prediction, Link_LCL, and Link_UCL: Prediction and Confidence Limits on link scale (i.e., log transformed)

If you wish to return back the 90th percent confidence value just change the critical value used to one corresponding to $\alpha$ = 0.10 instead of $\alpha$ = 0.05

Comment: @AnandSubramaniam Feel free to accept my answer if I helped you.

Comment: If I use statsmodels in Python to implement the same thing how do I ensure that my prediction is on the response scale. Statsmodels.api.glm doesn't have a predict function to predict on the response scale! :-(

Comment: Use the inverse link function on the prediction

Comment: My data is gamma distributed (clearly skewed to the right) but when I use the log link function the distribution that my model is producing is Gaussian. Not sure why. Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: @thecity2 The gamma can take on the shape of a normal Gaussian. Gamma is a series of distributions that changes shape depending on the data. Beyond the requirement of positive data only, it is very flexible. My guess is the log link is normalizing or nearly normalizing your data, same as a log transformation.